# sphinx multiple searchd on same port

Tags: sphinx

I am working on Sphinx search.
I have made  different indexes for different data.
My problem is ,i have different searchd services for different indexes.
But i want to run these all serivces on same port.Is it possible to do this in Sphinx?

Answer (score 2):

Each Sphinx daemon could serve multiple indexes. You just need to put all sources and indexes definition to single configuration file and make sure indexes has different names.

Quick example:

```
source src1
{
...
}

source src2
{
...
}

index sphinx_index1
{
    source                  = src1
    path                    = <sphinx_path>/sphinx_index1
    ...
}

index sphinx_index2
{
    source                  = src2
    path                    = <sphinx_path>/sphinx_index2
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps